# PhpStorm: auto correction of variable name

Tags: variables, phpstorm, autocorrect

Is there a way in PhpStorm to auto-correct typos in a variable name?
For example - when typing `$aCOuntry` instead of `$aCountry`, it should auto-correct it (this is happening very often due to releasing the shift key too late).

So there should be some kind of internal Typo-Dictionary.

Any ideas?

Comment: **1)** There is no spell auto correction. What if the word has meaning in your language (e.g. Romanian/German/French etc and you have no spellchecker dictionary for that language; or Russian/Ukrainian/etc word but written using Latin letters instead of Cyrillic?) **2)** You can use code completion popup to insert the variable name -- it will list the known variables/class members so you do not have to type it all and make a mistake in it.

Comment: You can also use Live Templates as auto correction .. but this will work for ordinary words mainly (unlikely to work on variables as it has the `$` sign). I'm using this to fix my common typos that I randomly do: `abn` or `adn` into `and`; `shoudl` into `should` etc. The idea here is to `Space` as an expand button instead of the default `Tab` .. so typing `abn[SPACE]` will auto-correct it for me into `and `

Comment: For reference purposes: the same on PhpStorm Forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/12513094783762-phpStorm-auto-correcting-variable-names